# How can I automatically backup Firefox bookmarks to a folder?

Tags: firefox, backup

I want to have Firefox backup my bookmarks to a selected folder every Sunday. How can I do that?

Comment: This extension should work for what you want: [Firefox Environment Backup Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/febe/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be the more general approach to use some backup tool to do this?

Comment: @bobSmith1432 nice add-on I think that suits me nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is implemented in [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner), which is an engine to write desktop applications in XML, JavaScript and a bunch of other web technologies. You could either write a [Firefox extension](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/) that does just that, or use an external application to back up bookmarks.html in your Firefox profile folder.

Comment: Slight comment on this: As of Firefox 3.0 bookmarks.html is not used, rather Firefox stores bookmarks and browsing history in [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox automatically keeps ten backups of your bookmarks.  On *nix-style systems, they are kept in the directory `~/.mozilla/firefox/somename/bookmarkbackups` (Windows should be analogous, probably in the users `Application Data` folder.).  If you want to keep your own copy of backups, you can mirror this directory to somewhere else using `rsync` or similar.

For information on restoring bookmarks from the backup files, see [mozilla's instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them).  In short:

- Click on "bookmarks"
- Click on "show all bookmarks".
- Click on "Import and Backup".  From here, you can "restore" from one of Firefox's ten saved backups.  (This menu also allows you to export or import the bookmarks as html.)

Comment: On Windows, it is "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles", e.g. "C:\Documents and Settings\SOMEUSER\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles".